# Get match of the set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let us imagine I have two tables

```
**T1**
T1ID
----
1
2
3

**T2**
T2ID| T1ID| VALUE|
------------------
   1|    1|     1|
   2|    1|     2|
   3|    2|     1|
   4|    2|     3|
   5|    2|     2|
   6|    3|     1|
   7|    3|     4|
```

T1 is a grouping table of values in T2
Therefore, I have three groups of values

```
1 = 1, 2
2 = 1, 2, 3
3 = 1, 4
```

Is it possible to write a query to get all groups, which match the set of values?

```
SELECT … WHERE VALUE IN (1, 2, 3)
SHOULD GIVE AS RESULT 
1
2

SELECT … WHERE VALUE IN (1, 4)
SHOULD GIVE AS RESULT 
3
```

one of answers below point me to dig in proper way:

```
SELECT s.t1id
  FROM (SELECT t1id, COUNT(value) itemCount
          FROM t2  
         WHERE VALUE IN (1, 2, 3) -- put set of values here
         GROUP BY t1id) s
  JOIN (SELECT t1id, COUNT(VALUE) itemCount
          FROM t2
         GROUP BY t1id) j 
    ON s.t1id = j.t1id 
 WHERE s.itemCount >= j.itemCount
```

Could someone improve the query?

Comment: in the first example why it should return 1?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ As posted there just isn't much information here and what information there is, is not very clear.

Comment: 2 Saeid, because this is subset of the (1,2,3) set

Comment: 2 Sean, thanks, this is good article about how to easier ask rare questions ;)

Comment: Let us imagine that instead of what you posted, you actually posted meaningful examples of your data, clearly explained what you were trying to accomplish, and asked a clearly stated, specific question. Think of how much more beneficial that would be to you, us, and the future readers who were reading this question while trying to solve their own problem.

Comment: Ken. I dont know why I answer you, but: 1. I care about solving my specific use case. 2. And I do not really care if some future reader will take something useful to him from my question. 3. The example data and expected results is pretty enough to give answer to my question (to sql developer). 4. If exactly you, whould like to be more useful to future readers, but not me (I do not see your answer) - rewrite my question with meaningful examples, answer on this question and be happy. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the below ... not sure if you use Oracle or not, but this seems to work.  Let me know if this is more efficient for you.

```
select *
from
(
    select  
    t1_id,
    LISTAGG(value, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) value_list
    from
    (
        select 1 t1_id, 1 value from dual union all
        select 1 t1_id, 2 value from dual union all
        select 2 t1_id, 1 value from dual union all
        select 2 t1_id, 3 value from dual union all
        select 2 t1_id, 2 value from dual union all
        select 3 t1_id, 1 value from dual union all
        select 3 t1_id, 4 value from dual
    )
    t2
    group by t1_id
)
where
instr('123',value_list) > 0
```

EDIT: I noticed the SQLServer tag ... just now.  Sorry about that.  So I've rewritten my solution in SQLServer syntax.

ADDITIONAL EDIT: Right you are ... I think the below will correct this behavior.  However, I cannot comment on the efficiency of the below approach.  I would imagine the in-line function of LISTAGG in Oracle may be more efficient - if only because smarter people than me have optimized it.

```
with t2 as
(
    select 1 t2_id, 1 t1_id, 1 value union all
    select 2 t2_id, 1 t1_id, 2 value union all
    select 3 t2_id, 2 t1_id, 1 value union all
    select 4 t2_id, 2 t1_id, 3 value union all
    select 5 t2_id, 2 t1_id, 2 value union all
    select 6 t2_id, 3 t1_id, 1 value union all
    select 7 t2_id, 3 t1_id, 4 value
)
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    b.t1_id,
    STUFF(CAST((
            SELECT [text()] = '' + cast(a.Value AS VARCHAR(100))
            FROM t2 a
            WHERE a.t1_id = b.t1_id
            ORDER BY a.Value
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(1000)), 1, 0, ''
    ) value_list
    from
    t2 b
) x
where
CHARINDEX(value_list,'123',1) > 0 OR
CHARINDEX('123',value_list,1) > 0
```

FINAL EDIT: Sorry I'd have done these in comments if I wasn't deemed too new a user to be allowed to leave comments.  I think you are correct.  I didn't fully understand the requirements, but I'm beginning to.  If say we add a value (1,3) into t2, my process will once again fail on a search for '123'.  I think my current solution is wrong, but I think there may be some merits to unpivoting and sorting to allow for more efficient pattern matching. Could probably do away with the LISTAGG portion of it, however. But, since, you've a working solution already, it may be best for me to bow out and obsess over more productive issues.

Sorry I didn't help, haha.  Good luck to you sir.

Comment: Thank Andy. I'm really appreciate your help. I tested your query. 1. It have a bug - lets imagine value=23 in t2 table. (for sure we can add delimited between values in value_list to fix it). 2. it have limitation with varchar length (1000) - for sure we can increase it also. 3. So the main question to you: could you please at least point me on the information describe that this type of the query (I never used such last 20 years) is faster | less load | whatever than query at the end of my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in several ways. Testing for the opposite ("not in list") can lead to interesting solutions:

```
 SELECT    t1id
 FROM      t2
 GROUP BY  t1id
 HAVING    COUNT(CASE WHEN value NOT IN (1,4) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The above query does not include those keys for which there is no value at all in table **t2**. Strictly speaking, an empty set is a subset of any other set, so those keys should actually be listed as well. With an outer join this can be achieved, like this:

```
 SELECT    t1.t1id
 FROM      t1
 LEFT JOIN t2
        ON t1.t1id = t2.t1id
 GROUP BY  t1.t1id
 HAVING    COUNT(CASE WHEN value NOT IN (1,4) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Or, with the `IN` test as an outer join condition:

```
 SELECT    t1.t1id
 FROM      t1
 LEFT JOIN t2
        ON t1.t1id = t2.t1id
       AND value NOT IN (1,4)
 WHERE     t2.t1id IS NULL
 GROUP BY  t1.t1id
```

Or, with a sub-query:

```
 SELECT   t1id
 FROM     t1
 WHERE    t1id NOT IN (SELECT t1id 
                       FROM   t2
                       WHERE  value NOT IN (1,4))
```

You could also use `MINUS`, which is quite intuitive:

```
 SELECT   t1id
 FROM     t1
 MINUS
 SELECT   t1id
 FROM     t2
 WHERE    t1id NOT IN (1,4)
```

Have a go and see what has the best performance in your case.